# My facebook tab app cannot post photo to page's wall when used by user NOT admin

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Alright, here's what I'm facing:

I have made an app for my facebook fan page, my app is a Facebook Page Tab app.

I have added the application to my facebook page by following:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

respectively, entering:

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL

and choosing which page to be added to.

When I have done this I did it with my Facebook Page Admin user.

I have allowed **manage_pages** and **publish_stream** and **publish_actions** permissions.

Here is my code:

```
$objFacebook = App_Utils_Facebook::getFacebook();

    $user_id = $objFacebook->getUser();
    $objFacebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);


    if(isset($_REQUEST['pageId'])){
        $arrPriv = $objFacebook->api("/".$_REQUEST['pageId']."/", array('fields'=>'access_token'));
        $link = 'http://link/here/'.$this->objAnunt->id;
    }


    $privacy = json_encode(array('value'=>'SELF'));

    if(isset($arrPriv['access_token'])){
        $access_token = $arrPriv['access_token'];
    }else{
        $access_token = $objFacebook->api("/".$_REQUEST['pageId']."/", array('fields'=>'access_token'));
    }


    if($user_id){
        try{
            $ret=$objFacebook->api("/".$arrPriv['id']."/photos",'POST',array(
                    'source'=>'@link/to/pic.jpg',
                    'message'=>$strTitle.'

                               For more details click here  '.$link,
                    'access_token'=>$access_token,
                    'privacy'=>$privacy
                                                )
            );
            unlink('link/to/pic.jpg');
        }catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
            echo $e;
        }
    }else{
            $permissions = $objFacebook->api("/me/permissions");
            if( !array_key_exists('publish_stream', $permissions['data'][0]) ||
            !array_key_exists('manage_pages', $permissions['data'][0])) {
                // We don't have one of the permissions
                // Alert the admin or ask for the permission!
                header( "Location: " . $objFacebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope" => "publish_stream, manage_pages")) );
            }
    }
```

So I repeat myself, I want to allow the average user to access my application and THE PAGE ITSELF to post on it's own wall.

Can I do it? If not are there any alternatives.

Thank you for your time and patience to help me figure this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you do not need the `manage_pages` permission to post to a page.

Please see [this documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#feed).

Making an API call to `/{page_id}/feed` using a valid user `access_token` should be enough to post to a page's feed.

---

As mentioned in the comments, Facebook probably doesn't allow a common user to upload photos to a page's albums. You'll need an `access_token` from an admin of that page (ensuring that the `manage_pages` permission is granted), retrive the page access token, and upload photos that way.

That page access token *should* be good for the life of the user access token.

Comment: well It doesn't! Using any other user AND providing that user access_token, I cannot post to /{page_id}/photos.

Comment: Ah, photos. In that case, it seems like Facebook does not allow the average user to upload photos to a page's albums. You'll need to make the `/{page_id]/photos` call using a page access token retrieved via a user with the `manage_pages` permission.

Comment: Ok, I've managed to get that access_token and indeed with the access_token of the admin, it publishes in the correct location. But, the question remains, can I store this access_token for later use so my application can function flawlesly? Thanks!

Comment: Yes indeed. The page access token (I believe) doesn't expire, or is it does, then it will expire *if the user token expires*. It should be good for between 60-90 days.